# ''A'' couple of people who ''do/does'' the same

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Let's say you are storytelling, and you say:

> "I currently take three or four ''mini-retirements'' per year and know **a** couple of *people* who **do/does** the same.''

This is a *subject-verb agreement* issue, which is confusing me right now, because I don't know which is to follow correctly if it is:

> - **''a couple''** then I will follow it with **does**
>
>   - **"people"** then I will follow it with **do**

Which is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to say that you know a couple of people who **do** the same. I agree that this is confusing, but "a couple" is used as a numerical adjective – just as if you said, "I know five people who do the same." Generally, in the US, when people say a couple of anything, they mean two, even if they are describing items that do not come in couples or pairs.

Comment: I get it now. May I ask, in your profile, what does ''recovering'' lawyer mean? Is it going back to school/as an already lawyer but something happened or something? Thx also.

Comment: @JohnArvin It’s a joke. In the US legal profession a recovering lawyer is someone who once worked as a lawyer but no longer does so. They may be said to be recovering in the same way one speaks of a revovering patient, or perhaps even a recovering alcoholic. It is somewhat of a tongue-in-cheek term.